# Is there a way to detect USB devices in an Android application on ChromeOS?

Tags: android, usb, google-chrome-os, chromebook, androidappsonchromeos

The device must be in [USB Host mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host) to use the [UsbManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager) class. However, when checking if the app is in USB Host mode using `packagemanager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_USB_HOST)`, it always returns false. Apparently, USB Host is an [unsupported feature](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/manifest.html#unsupported-hardware-features) on Chromebooks. Is there another way to detect when a USB is inserted on Android on Chromebooks?

We're transitioning from Chrome App to Android and [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/migration/) says to use a "Temporary* private USB host API" in place of the `chrome.usb` feature. But the link is broken and I can't find more information on it.

I've also tried the [USB Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USB) with no results (the app is contained within a webview, so thought it might work).

Comment: I am interested how you ended up handling USB on chromebook. Can you answer your question in the mean time?

Comment: I would consider building a web application that supports the USB features that you want and then distributing it as a TWA (Trusted web activity) using a Bubblewrap or PWABuilder. This would allow your app to appear as a downloadable app in the Google Play Store but run as a web app with all the features that you are familiar with in web developement.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the `state` property of the `StorageVolume`. A `StorageMediaState` value of `MOUNTED` will indicate a mounted USB drive. You also need to filter out non-USB drives by using the various properties of the attached `StorageVolume`s.

```
fun getStorageMediaStateFromVolume(volume: StorageVolume?): StorageMediaState {
    val volumeState = volume?.state
    return if (volume == null || volumeState == null) StorageMediaState.UNKNOWN
    else StorageMediaState.values().find { it.stringValue == volumeState } ?: StorageMediaState.UNKNOWN
}
```

```
enum class StorageMediaState(val stringValue: String, val isDriveInserted: Boolean) {
    // Unknown storage state, such as when a path isn't backed by known storage media.
    // This is the value when no drive is inserted.
    UNKNOWN(Environment.MEDIA_UNKNOWN, false),

    // Media is present but not mounted. Usually this state occurs after an ejection has completed
    // but the user has not yet removed the drive.
    UNMOUNTED(Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED, true),

    // Media is present and being disk-checked.
    CHECKING(Environment.MEDIA_CHECKING, true),

    // Media is present but is blank or is using an unsupported filesystem.
    NOFS(Environment.MEDIA_NOFS, true),

    // Media is present and mounted at its mount point with read/write access.
    MOUNTED(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED, true),

    // Media is present and mounted at its mount point with read-only access.
    MOUNTED_READ_ONLY(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY, true),

    // Media is present not mounted, and shared via USB mass storage.
    SHARED(Environment.MEDIA_SHARED, true),

    // Media is present but cannot be mounted, typically because the media's file system is corrupted.
    UNMOUNTABLE(Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE, true),

    // Media is in the process of being ejected.
    EJECTING(Environment.MEDIA_EJECTING, true),

    // Media is not present.
    REMOVED(Environment.MEDIA_REMOVED, false),

    // Media was removed before it was unmounted.
    BAD_REMOVAL(Environment.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL, false)
}
```